# Ignore all but some file types in a git directory

Tags: git, gitignore

I am having trouble to understand how to ignore all but some file extensions in a directory and all subdirectories in git.

I basically have a massive folder with many different file types in it and want to only commit .txt and .tex files in that folder and all its subfolders to git. Is there an easier way than putting all other file extension endings in the .gitignore file?

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You may try ignoring everything and then exclude `.txt` and `.tex` files anywhere from being ignored:

```
*
!*/
!*.txt
!*.tex
*/*
!*/*.txt
!*/.tex
```

Comment: After `*` you always need `!*/` to make sure Git will look inside directories that do not yet have any tracked files, if you want Git to complain about or add files in such directories.

Comment: ah ok, thanks a lot. So there is no way around telling .gitignore explicitly that I want to include all subdirectories

Comment: @torek Thanks for the edit.  I find that `.gitignore` is one of the least used and most poorly understood parts of Git.